# Display UIWebview HTML content in table row in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I am very new to iOS. I am creating one `table` based application where I need to display html contents in my `UIWebView` which is inside my `UITableViewCell`. The problem is when I am scrolling table view then my `webview` html contents are hiding and showing for the last `tableCell` and CellForRowAtIndexPath method is calling infinite time.

**Here is my code :**

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView
{

    aWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
    webViewHeight=fittingSize.height;

    [tblEventInfo reloadData];

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return webViewHeight;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    EventInfo *event = [[EventInfo alloc] init];
    event = [arrayEventInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSLog(@"%@", event.event_title);

    if(!webViewHTML)
    {
        webViewHTML = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
        webViewHTML.delegate = self;
        webViewHTML.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        webViewHTML.opaque = NO;
        webViewHTML.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        [webViewHTML loadHTMLString:event.event_html baseURL: nil];
    }

    [webViewHTML loadHTMLString:event.event_html baseURL: nil];

    webViewHTML.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, webViewHeight);

    [cell.contentView addSubview:webViewHTML];

    return cell;
}
```

Please help me, how can I resolve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

before

```
EventInfo *event = [[EventInfo alloc] init];
```

There are few changes I would suggest

```
EventInfo *event = [[EventInfo alloc] init];
event = [arrayEventInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

change it to

```
EventInfo *event = (EventInfo *)[arrayEventInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

as you already have object in the array
And another thing I would suggest is to keep the `webViewHTML` variable locally in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of UITableViewCell

Comment: I tried with your code, but still my problem is same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the individual tableviewcell identifier.
Try this below code

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellRow%d%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    EventInfo *event = [[EventInfo alloc] init];
    event = [arrayEventInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSLog(@"%@", event.event_title);

    if(!webViewHTML)
    {
        webViewHTML = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
        webViewHTML.delegate = self;
        webViewHTML.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        webViewHTML.opaque = NO;
        webViewHTML.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        [webViewHTML loadHTMLString:event.event_html baseURL: nil];
    }

    [webViewHTML loadHTMLString:event.event_html baseURL: nil];

    webViewHTML.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, webViewHeight);

    [cell.contentView addSubview:webViewHTML];
}
    return cell;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, By using your code now infinite loop problem got solved but only getting HTML (web view) for my last table cell. rest is coming blank.

Comment: Can you upload a sample app.